# Web API 2 Odata 4 Parameter Issue

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having problems defining a function for odata4.  The default get would work but I want to require a user parameter so a client set can be determined, other tables are involved so LINQ is required, I also return a DTO instead of the default table info (EF).  Below is the code.  I get a "Invalid EntitySetPath detected. 'bindingParameter/Client' is not a valid entity set path for procedure 'Default.GetClients'."  What am I doing wrong here?

**WebApiConfig**

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<client>("Client").EntityType.HasKey(p =>       p.int_id);

        var function = builder.Function("GetClients");
        function.Parameter<string>("user");
        function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<client>("Client");

        builder.EntitySet<ClientDTO>("ClientDTO");

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

**WebApp.Controller**

```
 [ODataRoute("GetClients(user={user})")]
    [EnableQuery(PageSize=25)]
    public IQueryable<ClientDTO> GetClients([FromODataUri] string user)
    {
         var clients = (from c in db.clients
                       join ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OData controller is returning the DTO, the function should look like this:

```
    var function = builder.Function("GetClients");
    function.Parameter<string>("user");
    function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ClientDTO>("Client");
```

With your current setup, your OData route of GetClients says that it is returning a `ClientDTO` object, but your WebApiConfig is stating you are returning a `Client` object.

As the Entity Collection being returned is actually the DTO.  The part that shows `("Client")` is simply how the OData service will report the name of the object to the project consuming the OData service.  For my own personal sanity, I typically include DTO as well so I know when I'm using a DTO and when I'm using a direct entity.  So in my own setup i'd return `("ClientDTO")`, just a personal preference.